# C# How to create an "UpdateGui" Method for async tasks (how to pass GUI control as variable)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, task

I'm trying to figure out how to create an "UpdateGUI" control as a method from a thread.  For example the following code works for a single GUI object just fine. But I can't figure out how to turn the RichTextBox "pingCheckStdOut" into a variable that will update any RichTextBox in my program. (Intended goal is to reduce duplicate code).

```
// RichTextBox pingCheckStdOut in Form1 created by the IDE: 
this.pingCheckStdOut = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

// my code: 
// Calling the async task from here 

private async void pingCheckInitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string ipAddress = pingCheckIpAddressBox.Text;
        string ldapUsername = usernameBox.Text;
        string ldapPassword = passwordBox.Text;
        string command = "";

 await Task.Run(() => sshAllStdOut(ipaddress, ldapUsername, ldapPassword, command));
    }

// the code I'm having trouble with (want to change pingCheckStdOut to a variable)

private async Task sshAllStdOut(string ipaddress, string ldapUsername, string ldapPassword, string command) 
    {
       SshClient client = new SshClient(ipaddress, 22, ldapUsername, ldapPassword);
        client.Connect();

        var stream = client.CreateShellStream("dumb", 120, 24, 360, 600, 1024);

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;

            while (stream.Length == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            WriteStream(command, writer, stream);

        while (client.IsConnected)
        {

            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {

//This is the line I'd like to convert into a "variable" for example:
// updateGUI(line, pingCheckStdOut) instead of passing directly
                updateGUI(line); 
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            if (line == "server_name:~ $ ")
            {
                                    client.Disconnect();
            }


        }




    }

/* This is my code to update the GUI from the thread */

delegate void SetTextCallback(string output);

    public void updateGUI(string input)
    {

        string output = input;


        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // It's on a different thread, use Invoke.
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke
                (d, new object[] { output });
        }
        else
        {
            // Else it's on the same thread, no need for Invoke
            this.pingCheckStdOut.Text = output;
        }
    }
    // This method is passed in to the SetTextCallBack delegate
    // to set the Text property of the RichTextBox.
    public void SetText(string output)
    {
        this.pingCheckStdOut.AppendText(output + "\n");
        pingCheckStdOut.ScrollToCaret();

     }
```

However, in this code I am only updating the RichTextBox control called "pingCheckStdOut".  I'm trying to figure out how to pass different GUI elements into this method.  So if I had another RichTextBox named "newProgramStdOut", how do I reuse this updateGUI() method?

I'm a new C# programer coming from Perl, so it's quite a bit different from what I'm used to. The intended goal of this program is to dump everything from SSH.Net console into a GUI in realtime in order to provide an "interface" for command-line scripts hosted on a Linux box.

Comment: What you are asking is very fundamental for C-like object oriented languages (C++, Java, C# etc.). Maybe you should read some material on those languages. Other than that, you CANNOT update a GUI element from a background thread and there's a possibility that `Task.Run` will run the task in a background thread.

Comment: Well, I know I can't touch the GUI from the non-GUI thread.  The code I posted works, I just want to optimize it by passing the RichTextBox Control as a variable instead of the single RichTextBox that the code above has.  I am still reading through C# books, but trying to write useful code while studying as well.

Comment: What you are asking is very similar in perl right? Just change `updateGUI` function to accept an additional parameter of type `RichTextBox`. Then instead of calling `updateGUI` only once, you can call it for each text box that you have.

Comment: ah ha! I had tried this before, but kept running into errors (I believe I also tried using Control control).  But knowing that "RichTextBox variable" was indeed the right way to pass it, I was able to also deduct that I needed to redo my invoke method to also pass the variable.  Thanks so much for pushing me in the right direction!  Changes to code below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed:

```
public void updateGUI(string input, RichTextBox guiElement)

this.Invoke
(d, new object[] { output, guiElement });

public void SetText(string output, RichTextBox guiElement)
    {
        guiElement.AppendText(output + "\n");
        guiElement.ScrollToCaret();


    }
```

Full Code:

```
private async Task sshAllStdOut(string ipaddress, string ldapUsername, string ldapPassword, string command) // work in progress
    {
        SshClient client = new SshClient(ipaddress, 22, ldapUsername, ldapPassword);
        client.Connect();

        var stream = client.CreateShellStream("dumb", 120, 24, 360, 600, 1024);

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;

            while (stream.Length == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            WriteStream(command, writer, stream);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            WriteStream("\n", writer, stream);


        while (client.IsConnected)
        {

            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                updateGUI(line, pingCheckStdOut);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

          if (line == "server_name:~ $ ")
            {
                client.Disconnect();

            }


        }




    }

   // this is to pull the data from the 2nd thread back into the main thread
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string output, RichTextBox guiElement);

    public void updateGUI(string input, RichTextBox guiElement)
    {

        string output = input;


        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // It's on a different thread, so use Invoke.
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke
                (d, new object[] { output, guiElement });
        }
        else
        {
            // Else it's on the same thread, no need for Invoke
            guiElement.Text = output;
        }
    }
    // This method is passed in to the SetTextCallBack delegate

 public void SetText(string output, RichTextBox guiElement)
    {
        guiElement.AppendText(output + "\n");
        guiElement.ScrollToCaret();


    }
```

Comment: Consider using `BeginInvoke(); return;` rather than `Invoke()` because the latter 1) blocks the worker thread and 2) is at risk of locking up the app entirely if the UI thread is already busy